# Node fs.stat name giving undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, stat, fs

When I do `console.log(stats)` in a `fs.stats` function for a file, it gives me something like this:

`{ dev: 16777223,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 49868100,
  size: 5617,
  blocks: 16,
  atime: Mon Jan 05 2015 18:18:10 GMT-0700 (MST),
  mtime: Thu Sep 25 2014 21:21:28 GMT-0600 (MDT),
  ctime: Thu Sep 25 2014 21:21:28 GMT-0600 (MDT),
  birthtime: Thu Sep 25 2014 21:21:28 GMT-0600 (MDT),
  name: 'README.md',
  type: 'file' }`

Here's the code, I'm using the [walk node plugin](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk). The function runs every time it finds a file.

```
walker.on('files', function(path, stats, next){
    console.log(stats.name);
    next();
});
```

But when I do `console.log(stats.name)`, it says that it is undefined. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Am I using the wrong property somehow?

Comment: Any how you are getting the results in String form,  you can check it, just convert in to JSON and try again

Comment: Do you have a bit more of your code here? `fs.Stats` doesn't have a `name` property

Comment: @jdphenix I added some code.

@aba `typeof stats` returns 'object'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using walker on `files` not walker on `file`. So stats might contain an array of files not only one. Try `console.log(stats)` to see the stats argument structure for `files`.

Or maybe try `walker.on('file', function(path, stats, next){});`

Comment: It's actually only one file that runs through the function. If it was more than one I wouldn't be able to console.log(stat).

Comment: Sorry, but your comment doesn't make much sense :). Why can't you console.log(stats) if there were more files?

Comment: Because I do not have a forEach to run through an array of files. "Files" means to look through files instead of directories.

Comment: You don't have an forEach, thats right, but you need one, to iterate over stats array. And yes, `'files'` looks through files, but it is also fired only after all files in dir are `stat`ed - so the stats attribute in your callback function is an array of file stats, not a file stat. If you want the callback function fired for each file and don't want to use a `forEach` in your function you need to listen to `file` event, not `files`

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Please read over the op again. I already did console.log( stats). It gives me the stats for each single file (an object).

Comment: I don't know what 'op' means. Have you tried changing "walker.on(`"files"` ..." to "walker.on(`"file"`, ..." and check the output of `console.log(stats.name)` ?

Comment: 'OP' means original post or original poster :). Sorry, coudln't try that earlier. I was on mobile. I just tried it though, it works! Thank you fou for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for `fs.Stats` there's no such `name` property. `fs.stat` is analogous with [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) which also doesn't have a name in the struct it returns either.

If you're wanting the filename, you don't even need to call `stat()`. Consider this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('.', function(err, entries) {
    // filenames available here in the array `entries`
    entries.forEach(function(filename) {
        fs.stat('./' + filename, function(err, stats) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(stats);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: @self Fair enough, doesn't change the simple fact that `fs.stat()` doesn't return something with a `name` property. :)

Comment: I added some code. There is a stat object, though. I should be able to get the name. `typeof stats` returns 'object'.